# html page can't find asset from Go web server

Tags: html, go

I have a Go HTTP web server and I'm loading static assets like so:

```
http.Handle("/assets/", http.StripPrefix("/assets/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("assets/"))))
```

The directory `assets` exist at the directory the web server is running, and the image file `assets/images/logo.svg` exist.

If I try going to `http://localhost/assets/images/logo.svg` it redirects to `http://localhost/`.

From an HTML page I have the following:

```
<img src="assets/images/logo.svg">
```

This fails to load the image.

I then tried the following as well with no luck:

```
<img src="./assets/images/logo.svg">
<img src="//localhost/assets/images/logo.svg">
```

Unsure what I'm doing wrong to host static files and being able to use them from html.

**EDIT**

I've added the code for everything [here](https://github.com/dangerousHobo/GoHtmlExample).
Along with a photo showing the broken images.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify the line from:

```golang
http.Handle(
    "/assets/",
    http.StripPrefix(
        "/assets/", 
        http.FileServer(http.Dir("assets/")),
    ),
)
```

to

```golang
http.Handle(
    "/assets/", 
    http.StripPrefix(
        "/assets/", 
        http.FileServer(http.Dir("./assets/")),
    ),
)
```

Please note, your `img`->`src` should be something like this `assets/images/logo.svg`

**EDITED**:
The below image is the response to the comment [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71918931/html-page-cant-find-asset-from-go-web-server/71918994#comment127108503_71918994):
[image]

Comment: After making these changes I'm still unable to have the server find the file. Still a 404 on `http://localhost/assets/images/logo.svg`.

Comment: @dangeroushobo Would you mind sharing the directory structure including files as tree format. Also mention which file contains this particular line `http.Handle(`

Comment: I shrunk my project down to the minimum to make it easy to look at. The entire project can be found here: https://github.com/dangerousHobo/GoHtmlExample
main.go contains all the Go code, 30 lines.

Comment: @dangeroushobo please refer to this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ya27o.png for your above comment.

Comment: Figured it would be something silly. Thanks for helping me track this down!